# Related Backbone elements on a single page

Tags: backbone.js

I have a sidebar and a main content view. The main content view will show the relevant content using Backbone.js when a menu item is clicked in the sidebar.

The sidebar menu item will update with any edits made in the content view. The page should not refresh the whole view, should operate like a tab view.

Question: What is the best method to setup these related elements on a single page using Backbone?

Comment: For convinient coding you shouldn`t use pure Backbone, instead use some superstructures like Marionett (https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette#readme ). View Wiki and samples - it will be useful.